# Syntax error using declare

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  syntax error when I use "declare" :

```
 delimiter $$
  begin

 declare @StartDay INT, @EndDay INT, @StartMonth INT, @EndMonth INT
 Select @StartDay = 01, @StartMonth = 10, @EndDay = 30, @EndMonth = 09

 Select year(a.created_at) as years , jd.JobDomain, count(a.Id) as nb_answer,   a.Job_id,   j.JobTitle 
 from JobAppliance a
 inner join Job j on a.Job_id =  j.PublicId
 inner join JobDestination d on j.Id=d.Job_id
 inner join Jjobdomain jd on  j.Id = jd.Job_id

 and 
 (
 @StartMonth = @EndMonth And 
 Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And 
 Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay And 
 Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
 ) Or (
 @StartMonth != @EndMonth And (
 (
 Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And
 Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay
 ) Or (
 Month(a.created_at) Between @StartMonth + 1 And @EndMonth - 1
 ) Or (
 Month(a.created_at) = @EndMonth And
 Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
 )
 )
)

group by year(a.created_at) , a.Job_id, j.JobTitle;

end$$
delimiter ;
```

Im using Mysql workbench

edit :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'@StartDay int, @EndDay int, @StartMonth int, 
     @EndMonth intSelect @StartDay = 0' at line 3
```

Comment: What does the syntax error say?

Comment: you cas take a look in edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the Line Delimiter

```
DELIMITER $$

DECLARE MyVal INT$$

SELECT
...
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

On the Other hand, why do you have to change the Delimiter?

And Declare should only be used between BEGIN and END as stated in the Documentation.
So if you are not using this part in a stored procedure (e.g. a simple Query) you can't use DECLARE

All Variables starting with an @ are Session Variables and do not need to be declared.

So here is a copy'n'paste for you

```
SET @StartDay = 01, @StartMonth = 10, @EndDay = 30, @EndMonth = 09; -- look here the ;

Select year(a.created_at) as years , jd.JobDomain, count(a.Id) as nb_answer,   a.Job_id,   j.JobTitle 
from JobAppliance a
inner join Job j on a.Job_id =  j.PublicId
inner join JobDestination d on j.Id=d.Job_id
inner join Jjobdomain jd on  j.Id = jd.Job_id

and 
(
@StartMonth = @EndMonth And 
Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And 
Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay And 
Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
) Or (
@StartMonth != @EndMonth And (
(
Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And
Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay
) Or (
Month(a.created_at) Between @StartMonth + 1 And @EndMonth - 1
) Or (
Month(a.created_at) = @EndMonth And
Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
)
)
)

group by year(a.created_at) , a.Job_id, j.JobTitle;
```

Comment: I dont understand what do u mean?You can change in my example please

Comment: it's my first time I use Declare so what I hope is just my query works fine,I dont know  a lot of thing about procedure too,any solution

Comment: @Nll you should try the copy'n'paste solution

Comment: Ok i see so you guess is equal

Comment: no, it is not equal, because you cannot declare (at this point) any variables, but you can use session variables. But now it should work as you expected, so it is equal to your needed solution :o)

Comment: I have another question ,now the query works fine but I have another question,then i get number of answers of one job grouped by year,so I hope also add in the same query,number of jobs posted for every year it's possible?

Comment: maybe if you have gmail account it will be more better

Comment: maybe if you have a look at the group by - group only by Year - but this has nothing to do with the question regarding declare, so you might open another question here on SO